Differentiability on an open interval around x0 implies that the derivative is continuous at x0?
I am trying to prove to myself if the statement : “f’ defined on (a-R,a+R) is enough to say that f’ is then continuous at a”. I tried to write a proof about this because I have a strong feeling or experience that this is the case but I am not sure. Thank you
